# Need to have div element to fill the height of its parent

Tags: html, css

I need to create an perfectly A4 sized document in a PHP code. Here's what I've done so far.

[image: Print Preview Document]

As you can see in the image above, there's an extra space below the 2 divs. I need to make these 2 divs fill the parent size.

Here's the HTML + CSS code:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      background-color: #FAFAFA;
    }
    
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    .page {
      width: 210mm;
      min-height: 297mm;
      margin: 10mm auto;
      border: 1px #D3D3D3 solid;
      border-radius: 5px;
      background: white;
      box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    }
    
    .subpage {
      height: 257mm;
      display: flex;
    }
    
    @page {
      size: A4;
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    @media print {
      html,
      body {
        width: 210mm;
        height: 297mm;
      }
      .page {
        margin: 0;
        border: initial;
        border-radius: initial;
        width: initial;
        min-height: initial;
        box-shadow: initial;
        background: initial;
        page-break-after: always;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="cv">
    <div class="page">
      <div class="subpage">
        <div style="background-color:#F8F8FF; width: 70%; height: 100%; min-height: 100%;">

        </div>
        <div style="background-color:#0BA9FE; width: 30%; display: flex; flex-direction: column;">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

What am I missing here? why don't the divs fit its parent height?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this how you were expecting ?

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      background-color: #FAFAFA;
    }
    
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    .page {
      width: 210mm;
      min-height: 297mm;
      margin: 10mm auto;
      border: 1px #D3D3D3 solid;
      border-radius: 5px;
      background: white;
      box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    }
    
    .subpage {
      height: 297mm;
      display: flex;
    }
    
    @page {
      size: A4;
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    @media print {
      html,
      body {
        width: 210mm;
        height: 297mm;
      }
      .page {
        margin: 0;
        height: 100%;
        border: initial;
        border-radius: initial;
        width: initial;
        min-height: initial;
        box-shadow: initial;
        background: initial;
        page-break-after: always;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="cv">
    <div class="page">
      <div class="subpage">

        <div style="background-color:#F8F8FF; width: 70%; height: 100%; min-height: 100%;">
        </div>

        <div style="background-color:#0BA9FE; width: 30%;">
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I see that I put the incorrect size of the 'subpage', instead of 257 its needs to be 297, and you removed height attribute at the 'page' section in CSS. thank you. Your code works as I expected.

Answer (score 0):

set the height of .page class to `auto`

```
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      background-color: #FAFAFA;
    }

    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .page {
      width: 210mm;
      height: auto;
      margin: 10mm auto;
      border: 1px #D3D3D3 solid;
      border-radius: 5px;
      background: white;
      box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);

    }

    .subpage {
      height: 257mm;
      display: flex;
    }

    @page {
      size: A4;
      margin: 0;
    }

    @media print {
      html,
      body {
        width: 210mm;
        height: 297mm;
      }
      .page {
        margin: 0;
        border: initial;
        border-radius: initial;
        width: initial;
        min-height: initial;
        box-shadow: initial;
        background: initial;
        page-break-after: always;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="cv">
    <div class="page">
      <div class="subpage">
        <div style="background-color:#F8F8FF; width: 70%; height: 100%; min-height: 100%;">

        </div>
        <div style="background-color:#0BA9FE; width: 30%; display: flex; flex-direction: column;">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion. Changing the height of .page to auto did solve the issue on the page, but there is still gap in the print preview window.

Comment: the gap is because the margin,padding in your code does not contain "px".

Answer (score 0):

```
height: 100%;
```

Setting the height of page class in CSS will bring the desired effect, You can also specify the height accordingly by changing its value.